# Nullable parameter in WebMethod

Tags: vb.net, parameters, nullable

Can I add `nullable` property to `"id_client"` parameter in this WebMethod?

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function find_client(ByVal auth_login As String, ByVal client_id As Long) As String
//code
End Function
```

When I try to test this Web Service in a browser and I don't set anything in `id_client` parameter then I get **Conversion Error (String to int64)**.
If I add optional property to this parameter I get **Syntax error** appear in Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to improve this question. It isn't entirely clear what you are asking. Please also describe the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If I want to test this web service in browser and I d'ont set anything in id_client parameter => Conversion Error appaer  (String to int64)  .If I add optional property to this parameter => Syntaxe error appear In visual Studio

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure what you mean.. but you can set client_id to be optional. Then the function can be called with or without the client_id.

For example

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function find_client(ByVal auth_login As String, Optional ByVal client_id As Long = Nothing) As String

 //code
End Function
```

Comment: This error will appear: <br> attribute 'webmethod' cannot be applied to a method with optional parameters

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do? are you trying to call the function with client_id = nothing?

Comment: I have a syntaxe error in Visual Studio , before call or test the function

Comment: so you've tried `find_client("me", Nothing)`? can you post the code inside your function, i suspect this is where the problem is

Comment: <WebMethod()> _
Public Function find_client(ByVal auth_login As String, ByVal client_id As Long) As String
return "OK"
 
End Function

Comment: So have you tried calling your function with `nothing` as the value for the `client_id` parameter? e.g. `find_client("me", Nothing)`